# Публикация Excel таблицы, с разными данными в зависимости от авторизации пользователя

Tags: excel, office, nextcloud, onlyoffice

Всем привет, кто может подсказать как решить следующую задачу, без создания целого сервиса фронт->бэкенд)) Требуется вывесить в интернете, ну или в локалке Excel таблицу (прайс) в зависимости кто залогинился п1 или п2, чтобы они видели разные данные, например для п1 считалось от main +0.7%, а для п2 0.9% можно вывесить 2 таблицы, но как сделать чтобы они брали данные из main?

Пробовал публикации на облаках, ЯД, Nexcloud + сервера с OnlyOffice или доки от Яндекс + закрывал это череp Nginx proxy + Access rule c редиректами на расшареные таблицы, везде одна проблема, рвутся формулы main + 0.7%

Есть идеи?

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как в Google таблицах такое можно сделать.

Т.е. сделать один основной лист. В нем, например, в колонке **A** - указываем базовую цену. В колонке **B** считаем цену по одной формуле с использованием данных из колонки **А**. А в колонке **C** считаем по другой формуле.

А дальше добавляются другие листы. На один лист выводятся данные с первого листа из колонки **B**, а на другой лист данные из колонки **С**

И соответственно доступ к разным листам дается разным людям.

А основная цена меняется на первом листе. В результате цены пересчитываются по формуле в колонках и выводится в соответствующих листах.

Comment: спасибо, попробую